# Javascript activating/deactivating functions based on selection

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I am developing a web map. This map should include two tools (layerswipe and layerspy) for the user to explore differences between two overlayed layers.

My goal is to create two radio buttons where one of the tool gets activated when the corresponding radio button is selected.

The radio buttons:

```
<div class="toolbar-centered">
        <input type="radio" id="swipelayer" name = "mainfunction" onclick="mainfunx()" > Swipe
        <input type="radio" id="layerspy" name = "mainfunction" onclick="mainfunx()"> Layer spy
</div>
```

My javascript function to change between the two tools (tools are defined as `swipefunction()` and `spyfunction()`):

```
function mainfunx() {
 var s = document.getElementById('swipelayer').checked,
     p = document.getElementById('layerspy').checked;
 if (s) swipefunction()
 if (p) spyfunction()
}
```

Once I change my selection on the radio buttons, the tools do not get deactivated. Instead both are activated at the same time. I am very new to Javascript and do not really have a clue how to make sure that the other function is deactivated while the other is activated.

Comment: You can't really "deactivate" function in this sense. You call it and it runs making the changes you wrote it to do. You could save the state of the application and reverse to it or monitor the actions and undo them. But there is probably easier solution. Can you share you tools functions? Maybe we can help from there.

Comment: This is the code I used for spyfunction:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-spy.html
This is the code I used for swipefunction:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-swipe.html

Comment: Are you using the same canvas for both of the renders? If so, you could clear it before rendering the next one.